# XPath for text of node?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, domxpath

I'm trying to get to the content of STRING-VALUE where comparator has VALUE = item.auxiliaryData.productRef.brandName

I tried to use the following code,

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile
                ("//comparator[contains(VALUE,'item.auxiliaryData.productRef.ancestorCategoryIds')]//STRING-VALUE");
        productRefs = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

This is what I'm trying to parse

```
                    <comparator NAME="equals">
                       <VALUE>item.auxiliaryData.productRef.brandName</VALUE>
                       <CONSTANT>
                          <DATA-TYPE>java.lang.STRING</DATA-TYPE>
                          <STRING-VALUE>Ariat</STRING-VALUE>
                       </CONSTANT>
                    </comparator>
                    <comparator NAME="equals">
                       <VALUE>item.auxiliaryData.productRef.ID</VALUE>
                       <CONSTANT>
                          <DATA-TYPE>java.util.Collection</DATA-TYPE>
                          <STRING-VALUE>84332</STRING-VALUE>
                          <STRING-VALUE>79904</STRING-VALUE>
                          <STRING-VALUE>82203</STRING-VALUE>
                       </CONSTANT>
                    </comparator>
```

Comment: Ok. What are you getting ?

Comment: You are using `contains(X, Y)` where you probably intended `X=Y`. This is a common mistake: people think "node contains value". But `contains()` tests for a substring, and is more expensive: `contains(<A>foxy</A>, 'xy')` is true. However, I doubt this is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
string(//comparator[VALUE='item.auxiliaryData.productRef.brandName']//STRING-VALUE)
```

will return `"Ariat"` directly as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath needs to be corrected :

`//comparator[contains(VALUE,'item.auxiliaryData.productRef.brandName')]//STRING-VALUE`

You were using `item.auxiliaryData.productRef.ancestorCategoryIds`